# Microsoft Async RPC crash in Vista

Tags: windows, crash, operating-system, rpc, windows-vista

I am working on a program that makes RPC calls where the client and the server are running on the same machine. I want the client have a timeout on its calls to the server because we ran into problems of it becoming unresponsive waiting on the server.

In order to solve this problem, we used an asynchronous RPC call and canceled it if timed out.

This was working fine in XP, but now I am finding crashes in Vista and I have a test program that can reproduce these crashes every time (only in Vista, not in XP). It seems to be a bug on Microsoft's side. The call stack from the crashed thread does not include any calls to our code. Here is the info from the crash dump:

```
Call stack:
rpcrt4!_SEH_epilog4_GS+0x3979
rpcrt4!LRPC_CCALL::AbortCall+0x68
rpcrt4!LRPC_BASE_CCALL::HandleCancelMessage+0x6b
rpcrt4!LRPC_CCALL::HandleCancelMessage+0x42
rpcrt4!LRPC_CASSOCIATION::IoCompleted+0x341
rpcrt4!ProcessLrpcComplete+0x3b
rpcrt4!LOADABLE_TRANSPORT:Stick out tonguerocessIOEvents+0x212
rpcrt4!ProcessIOEventsWrapper+0xd
rpcrt4!BaseCachedThreadRoutine+0x5c
rpcrt4!ThreadStartRoutine+0x1e
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x23
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

Problem:
(ee4.139c): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not
available)
eax=01e0fcc4 ebx=002f8930 ecx=002f87e4 edx=002f87fc esi=002f87b0 edi=00000000
eip=76f08d9e esp=0200fe2c ebp=0200fe34 iopl=0 nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=001b ss=0023 ds=0023 es=0023 fs=003b gs=0000 efl=00010206
rpcrt4!_SEH_epilog4_GS+0x3979:
76f08d9e a300000000 mov dword ptr ds:[00000000h],eax
ds:0023:00000000=????????
```

I was wondering if anyone has had a similar problem and had found a work around? Maybe it is better to use something other than RPC for this situation?

Comment: Is this the server or the client crashing? What is "Stick out tongue"? is that TRACE/OutputDebugString output?